# Implementation of VFH in ROS

Tags: ros, local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I would like to know, is there the implementation of the Vector Field Histogram(VFH) method for 2D mobile robot navigation in ROS?

I know ROS has implemented the Dynamic Window Approach(DWA) in the "navigation" stack, but it seems that this is not very suitable for the holonomic robot. Although the "Player" has the implementation of VFH, it cannot be used directly in ROS, so is there the ROS version of it? Or is there the implementation of other state of the art for local motion plan especially for holonomic robot in ROS? I would appreciate for any clues or suggestions, thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46626/implementation-of-vfh-in-ros/) by [Mike Gao](https://answers.ros.org/users/1629/mike-gao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 108 on 2012-10-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2012-10-24**:
@Mike Gao This should interest you - http://answers.ros.org/question/12151/potential-field-navigation-implementation-in-ros/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Note that the DWA local planner is used on the PR2 (holonomic base), though it was written to drive mostly forward because of 3d sensor coverage in front of the robot (tilting laser).
With suitable parameters / customisation the DWA approach works well for holonomic bases.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-10-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1